# Converting html tags to docx and updating TOC using XML in php

Tags: php, xml, ms-word

I need to implement a module for exporting html to docx document in PHP. I created a template and set some variables inside. I am replacing these variables to data queried from database. It was working while there have occured the need to add some html tags with style attributes and TOC. I was using str_replace to convert some simple tags like `<br/>`, `<p>` and etc, but it is not working if add styling attributes like align and color.

1. Is there any ready **open source** systems to convert html tags including its styles to word?
2. Can I create a TOC after all the replace have been done?

Answer (score 0):

I use http://phpword.codeplex.com/ to do this.

The way I use it: upload an existing doc with tags like `%name%` in it.
These tags will be replaced by `$name` variable and the system will output the new document.

In order to fix a bug where phpword was unable to replace variables I had to modified the `Template.php` file. Look for the method `setValue` and change the function to:

```
$pattern = '|\$\{([^\}]+)\}|U';
preg_match_all($pattern, $this->_documentXML, $matches);
$openedTagPattern= '/<[^>]+>/';
$closedTagPattern= '/<\/[^>]+>/';
foreach ($matches[0] as $value) {
    $modified= preg_replace($openedTagPattern, '', $value);
    $modified= preg_replace($closedTagPattern, '', $modified);

    $this->_header1XML = str_replace($value, $modified, $this->_header1XML);
    $this->_header2XML = str_replace($value, $modified, $this->_header2XML);
    $this->_header3XML = str_replace($value, $modified, $this->_header3XML);
    $this->_documentXML = str_replace($value, $modified, $this->_documentXML);
    $this->_footer1XML = str_replace($value, $modified, $this->_footer1XML);
    $this->_footer2XML = str_replace($value, $modified, $this->_footer2XML);
    $this->_footer3XML = str_replace($value, $modified, $this->_footer3XML);
}

if(substr($search, 0, 2) !== '${' && substr($search, -1) !== '}') {
    $search = '${'.$search.'}';
}

if(!is_array($replace)) {
    $replace = utf8_encode($replace);
}

$this->_header1XML = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->_header1XML);
$this->_header2XML = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->_header2XML);
$this->_header3XML = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->_header3XML);
$this->_documentXML = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->_documentXML);
$this->_footer1XML = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->_footer1XML);
$this->_footer2XML = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->_footer2XML);
$this->_footer3XML = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->_footer3XML);
```

Comment: It is not working. I have added variable in Word like ${name} and replaced it using phpword function setvalue, but it generates incorrect document if I use html tags for replace.

Comment: Throws an exception about undefined property of _documentXML. I have added those properties and no error were messaged, but file was not saved did you miss something?

Comment: This is working for me. We use it in a production environment like this. Make sure you read the documentation for correct use of the script.